# Neo4j export SVG file with Python

Tags: python, svg, neo4j, py2neo

What I am trying to achieve is to execute a `cypher` query and get the SVG file from the result using `Python`. I couldn't find a way to export the SVG file with `py2neo` module. Is there a way to export the SVG file through `Python`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Py2neo has no graph drawing facilities built in. You will have to pair your code with another library such as [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/).